# Does Sonar support multiple language in same project?

Tags: java, groovy, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am setting up `Sonar` for one of my projects which is a mix of `Groovy` and `Java`. I am able to configure the project separately for either of these languages but not together. Is there any way to do this? I tried this

> sonar.language = java,grvy

but didnt work

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**UPDATE April 14th, 2014:**

Starting with SonarQube 4.2, multi-language projects are supported.

This automatically happens when `sonar.language` is not set.

See my sample project here: https://github.com/bellingard/multi-language-project

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam, can we do the same with maven? And if yes, do you have any examples? Thanks! p.s. that example on the git hub doesn't actually help, because we have different languages in one source folder.

Comment: @mr.nothing You can probably check Neeraj's answer below as well

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam We have a solutions containing projects containing a mix of Javascript, C# and Xsd files.
Looking at the .NET example: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-dotnet I don't see how you descripbe to Sonar which languages to analyse? It just seems to has 'cs' in the sonar-project.properties file.

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarTeam I think I must be missing something, why did you add to your answer that Sonar 3.3 and runner 2.0 can analyse multi-language projects?

Comment: Does it work for a project with both Groovy (grvy) and Java source/test code or mixed? I don't think it's working (sonar.language=grvy,java)

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarQubeTeam I tried it and got this. Can you please comment on that, thanks Fabrice. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154607/groovy-project-sonar-publish-project-and-unit-integration-test-code-covera

Comment: We are using v5.5 but it still doesn't pick the js files located in 'resources' folder. I looked at the example, there is no special configuration.. have I missed anything?

Comment: @Fabrice-SonarSourceTeam the link https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/languages/multi-language/multi-language-dotnet has broken. I am trying to configure C# and JavaScript, but it works only for C# and overrides C# test counts when I set sonar.tests='js-tests-dir'. I cant see both counts in dashboard

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sonar version 3.4. Then I have written a new maven plugin to 
help you with multiple language code analysis.

It is still beta

https://code.google.com/p/sonar-multilang-maven-plugin/wiki/UserGuide

If you have any issues with this tool then do let me know on that project website.

Answer (score 0):

Until  https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-926 is implemented you can use the combination of sonar.branch and sonar.language properties to analyze separately the project languages and have two different projects in your dashboard.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the use of sonar.branch? My project is a mix of java and groovy mixed together. I mean there is no separation of src folders