# Sonar Unit tests report parameter - sonar.junit.reportPath vs sonar.java.junit.reportPath

Tags: junit, gradle, sonarqube, sonar-runner, gradle-2

I found that my Sonar instance 5.1 or 5.1.1 (with latest sonar-runner 2.x) stopped showing part of the Unit test info (Unit test widget) on the project's dashboard.

The properties I had were (in Gradle's sonarRunner > sonarProperties section):

```
     property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
     property "sonar.surefire.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
```

To fix it, I had to include the following properties as well:

```
     property "sonar.java.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
     property "sonar.java.surefire.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
```

**Just FYI**: All my Unit tests reports go under *build/test-results/UT* folder, all Integration Tests result files go unedr *build/test-results/IT* folder and etc.

I'm wondering if this is due to Gradle version that I'm using (2.3) or is it due to a later version of SonarQube (4.5+) as I have both SQ 5.1 and 5.1.1 instance.
I know SonarQube team started Multi language support since SonarQube version 4.12

*Since SonarQube 4.2, it is possible to run an analysis on a multi-language project.*

Now, it raises a question. For Getting the same Unit test info for Groovy based projects, do I need to use:

```
     property "sonar.groovy.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
     property "sonar.groovy.surefire.reportsPath", "build/test-results/UT"
```

something like that if my project has Groovy code instead of java?

Searching **"**sonar.java.junit.reportPath**"** with using double quotes shows **No results found** in Google and it forces me to try and see google results if I can run the search again without using " double quotes (for this property).

Doing the same in SonarQube site "search box" shows:

*No results found for **sonar.java.junit.reportPath**. Please try one of the following suggestions:*

Though in Gradle, inside

```
 sonarRunner task { 
       .. inside ..
       sonarProperties { 
          ... section ... where I define various sonar props..
       } 
       ... 
  }
```

I can define both sonar.junit.reportPath, sonar.java.junit.reportPath and similarly, sonar.surefire.reporPath and sonar.java.surefire.reportPath and while running sonarRunner task in Gradle, it doesn't error out. Thus it makes me believe that the property variables are valid.

There are also issues with running sonarRunner or stand alone sonar-runner command for a mixed Java and Groovy based project (i.e. source code in Java but tests in Groovy). Setting `sonar.language=java,grvy` didn't help. I posted this question on stackoverflow but so far I have no perfect result/answer on how to get a full fledged sonar dashboard up and running for a Groovy projects like I get for a Java project.

[Groovy project - Sonar - Publish project and Unit + Integration Test code coverage data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154607/groovy-project-sonar-publish-project-and-unit-integration-test-code-covera)

**PS**: I have tried various values for setting sonar.*.* variables (as far a sonar source, tests, etc, etc properties are concerned, which they have mentioned on their site's docs section)

Answer (score 0):

The only valid property to use as of now is `sonar.junit.reportsPath` which will tell the *java* sonarqube plugin where to import your result of unit tests.

For groovy, this is work in progress, see : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGROOV-2

All the other properties you mentioned do not exist and are not taken into account.